# What does Features column represent in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play

I've just uploaded a new bundle to the Google Play console.

The summary has a Features column, which currently says 4 in my new build but was 2 in my last build.

[image: screenshot]

What does the Features column represent?

And bonus question, how can I tell what those 4 Features are (vs the 2 in last build)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clicking on dropdown icon:

[image]

Reveals "Features" line with details :

[image]

I'm guessing that this refers to attributes that are imported using `uses-feature` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. [Here's the list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#features-reference) of all possible values in doc.

Note, that transitive dependencies might declare `uses-feature` themselves, thus you might see this number increasing though you haven't added that attribute yourself.